# simplexml_load_string returns blank array

Tags: php, xml, soap, curl

I am using a 3rd party web service to post the request and get the response via soap using php curl.The response is fine but for some reason I can't parse the response.When I use simplexml_load_string it gives me blank.

My code is

```
// PHP cURL  for https connection with auth

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $soapUser.":".$soapPassword); // username and password - declared at the top of the doc
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_ANY);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $xml_post_string); // the SOAP request
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

// converting
$response = curl_exec($ch);              
print_r($response); // when I print response it shows me the correct response with data.
but when I am doing ,

$parser = simplexml_load_string($response2);         
print_r($parser); // it's giving SimpleXMLElement Object ( )
```

The header is

```
$headers = array(
                        "Content-type: text/xml;charset=\"utf-8\"",
                        "Accept: application/xml",
                        "Cache-Control: no-cache",
                        "Pragma: no-cache",

                        "Content-length: ".strlen($xml_post_string),
                    );
```

The soap header is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
                            <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ws="http://ws.mrted.com/">

   <soapenv:Header>

      <wsse:Security soapenv:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">

         <wsse:UsernameToken wsu:Id="UsernameToken-1">

            <wsse:Username>*********************:guest:FO</wsse:Username>

            <wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">guest</wsse:Password>

            <wsu:Created>2012-07-09T11:35:20.019Z</wsu:Created>

         </wsse:UsernameToken>

      </wsse:Security>

   </soapenv:Header>
```

**The response which I am getting is after printing curl response in browser --**

```
 <env:envelope xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <env:header></env:header>
    <env:body>
    <ns2:getcriteriaresponse xmlns:ns2="http://ws.mrted.com/">
    <ns2:standardcriteriawithlovs>
    <adlanguages><language><label>English (UK)</label><value>UK</value></language></adlanguages>
 <countries><country><label>Australia</label><value>1116</value><regions><region><label>Australian Capital Territory</label><value>3027</value></region><region><label>New South Wales</label><value>3028</value></region><region><label>Northern Territory</label><value>3029</value></region><region><label>Queensland</label><value>3030</value></region><region><label>South Australia</label><value>3031</value></region><region><label>Tasmania</label><value>3032</value></region><region><label>Victoria</label><value>3033</value></region><region><label>Western Australia</label><value>3034</value></region></regions></country><country><label>United Kingdom</label><value>1290</value><regions><region><label>East Anglia</label><value>3429</value></region><region><label>East Midlands</label><value>3430</value></region><region><label>England</label><value>4329</value></region><region><label>London</label><value>3431</value></region><region><label>Midlands</label><value>3432</value></region><region><label>North East</label><value>3433</value></region><region><label>North West</label><value>3434</value></region><region><label>Northern Ireland</label><value>3435</value></region><region><label>Scotland</label><value>3436</value></region><region><label>South</label><value>4332</value></region><region><label>South East</label><value>3437</value></region><region><label>South West</label><value>3438</value></region><region><label>Wales</label><value>3439</value></region><region><label>West Midlands</label><value>3440</value></region></regions></country></countries>
    </ns2:standardcriteriawithlovs>
    </ns2:getcriteriaresponse>
    </env:body>
    </env:envelope>
```

It is sure that, I am getting the data but the format might be wrong or I am missing something.

Please suggest.Many thanks in advance.

Comment: That's because SimpleXML doesn't return an array, it returns nested collection of SimpleXML Element Objects; you need to load it and then parse it to locate what you need, which can then be cast to string/integer/float/etc

Comment: Thanks Mark.Do you have any reference manual how to load and then parse please.

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php is a good page to start

Comment: Thanks for the link.I checked it. The document tree starts with the below thing.
      <env:Envelope><env:Header/><env:Body><ns2:getCriteriaResponse><ns2:standardCriteriaWithLovs><adLanguages><language><label>English (UK)</label><value>UK</value></language></adLanguages>......so on.I am bit confused where to start from I mean after doing $response = curl_exec($ch);  $res = new SimpleXMLElement($response); how can I fetch the adlanguages node.

Comment: Awkward because that doesn't look like the full xml, as there's no namespace definitions: can you edit the full xml (exactly as you get it from the curl call) into your question?

Comment: Right.Even it is not a full xml.When I do print_r($response) it just prints the text in browser and then I go to (firebug > net panel) copy the response body and then put in a xml file.Then I can see the full xml tree.

Comment: I have edited my post so that you can see the header and soap header section.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$response2 = <<<EOF
<env:envelope xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <env:header></env:header>
    <env:body>
        <ns2:getcriteriaresponse xmlns:ns2="http://ws.mrted.com/">
            <ns2:standardcriteriawithlovs>
                <adlanguages>
                    <language>
                        <label>English (UK)</label>
                        <value>UK</value>
                    </language>
                </adlanguages>
            </ns2:standardcriteriawithlovs>
        </ns2:getcriteriaresponse>
    </env:body>
</env:envelope>
EOF;

$parser = simplexml_load_string($response2);  
$parserEnv = $parser->children('env', true);
$languages = $parserEnv->body->children('ns2', true)
    ->getcriteriaresponse->children('ns2', true)
    ->standardcriteriawithlovs->children()
    ->adlanguages->children();

foreach($languages as $language) {
    $label = (string) $language->label;
    $value = (string) $language->value;
    echo $label, ' => ', $value, PHP_EOL;
}
```

Comment: From now on you are my guru.It's just brilliant piece of coding.Thank you so much.One last thing that is if I have the countries as children of 'standardcriteriawithlovs' and under countries I have got two countries and I want to select the second country's all of the regions(the response is in my post) then will it be $languages = $parserEnv->Body->children('ns2', true)
    ->getCriteriaResponse->children('ns2', true)
    ->standardCriteriaWithLovs->children()
    ->countries->children()->country[1]->children(); ?

Comment: I'd loop through the `standardcriteriawithlovs->children()` using the getName() method to test if each child was an adlanguage or a country, then looping through each of those children's children to get the individual language or country details; but you could use your direct approach as long as you know the countries will always be there

Comment: let me try with the getName() method.

Comment: Solved...I have used getName to identify the country and then again foreach loop to get into it's children nodes....it's absolutely lovely experience.Thank you so much for this.

Comment: Namespaces are a painful learning experience with SimpleXML, but once you've got your head round them they're fairly straightforward

Comment: true...now I am flying with xml...thanks for showing me the first light.